# Making a table with generated array C- programming

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

My program should ask user how many numbers he wanna input in the array , and than input one by one. Any number that's higher than 99 should be replaced by '0'.

That part works fine. But in the end created array should be placed in the table which needs to be in format (5 columns / depending rows).

This is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 80

int main()
{
  int n = 0;
  int i,j;
  int field[MAX]={0};

  printf("how many numbers do u want to input? ");
  scanf("%d",&n);



  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("Input number %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&field[i]);
    if(field[i] / 100 >= 1 )
    {
      field[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  for ( i = 0; i<n; i++)
  {
    printf("\nfield[%d] = %d\n", i, field[i]);
  }
  for(i=0; i <= 5;i+=5)
  {
    for(j =i; j <n;j++)
    {
      printf("%d ",field[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the division for checking if the value is larger than `99`? Why not simply `field[i] > 99`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Acctually, the program says " replace all numbers that's not one-digit or two-digits by '0' " - so it's not working if i type in negative number. but in this case my problem is that last nested loop for creating table with.

Comment: my question is how to create  that table  with that array that's created.

Comment: **Unclear question.** Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. [Use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program, then improve it. Repeat all this till satisfied.

Comment: BTW the `MAX` name is likely to collide with some existing macro (so use some longer name). And if your user inputs something bigger than 80, you have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every function you are using. And **edit your question** to improve it (e.g. with some [MCVE] and a *clearly stated* question). Don't comment your own question. You could want to use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch when i input for example 10 numbers(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9), it outputs : 1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  9
                                                                 1   2  3  4  5
and i want it to be   1  2  3  4  5
                               6  7  8  9  9

Comment: like in the table 5 numbers under  5 numbers

Comment: Don't comment your own question. But do take time to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code can not be output in five columns

```
 for(i=0; i <= 5;i+=5)
  {
    for(j =i; j <n;j++)
    {
      printf("%d ",field[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

So if you change this, it will be executed

```
  for(i=0; i <n;i+=5)
      {
        for(j =i; j <i+5;j++)
        {
          printf("%d ",field[j]);
        }
    printf("\n");

      }
```

I hope this code will be help.

if i am wrong, please tell me and give a chance.
I want to help you and be recognized.